# ggplot stacked bar graph with 2 columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create a stacked bar graph of my data frame `df` without having to transform the data, for interpretability reasons. My data looks like this:

```
#Code
year <- c(1:5)
burglaries <- c(234,211,201,150,155)
robberies <- c(12, 19,18,23,25)
total <- burglaries + robberies
df <- data.frame(year, burglaries, robberies, total)

#Output
print(df)

  year burglaries robberies total
1    1        234        12   246
2    2        211        19   230
3    3        201        18   219
4    4        150        23   173
5    5        155        25   180
```

I can create the plot I need by transforming my data set as follows:

```
df2 <- rbind(
        data.frame(year, "count" = burglaries, "type"="burglaries"),
        data.frame(year, "count" = robberies, "type"="robberies")
)

ggplot(df2, aes(x=year, y=count, fill=type)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Is there a way to create the same plot with the data frame `df`? Although I could transform the data, I worry it'll make it harder to follow what's happening in the program and catch errors (the data set I'm using is quite large).

Comment: You're working against the way ggplot was specifically designed to be used. ggplot _wants_ you to transform (melt, gather, tidy, whatever you want to call it) your data first. So the short answer is no, not really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some additional research and found the `plot_ly()` function from the library `plotly` allows you to do just that. Here's the link for more info: [plotly website](https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/)

```
plot_ly(data=df, x = ~year, y = ~burglaries, type = 'bar', name = 'Burglaries') %>%
    add_trace(y = ~robberies, name = 'Robberies') %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'stack')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately a transformation is required but a more elegant way is to use tidyr:

```
df %>% 
   select(-total) %>% 
   gather(type, count, burglaries:robberies) %>% 
   ggplot(., aes(x=year, y=count, fill=forcats::fct_rev(type))) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity")
```